# HTML to PDF in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dnx, dnx50

Any idea of how to run http://selectpdf.com/pdf-library-for-net/ or other similar library in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 (DNX 4.5.1)

Answer (score 1):

You can yse [evopdf](http://www.evopdf.com/) for this. 
Sample code: http://www.evopdf.com/demo/default.aspx:

```
  protected void convertToPdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  // Create a HTML to PDF converter object with default settings
  HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

  // Set license key received after purchase to use the converter in licensed mode
  // Leave it not set to use the converter in demo mode
  htmlToPdfConverter.LicenseKey = "4W9+bn19bn5ue2B+bn1/YH98YHd3d3c=";

  // Set HTML Viewer width in pixels which is the equivalent in converter of the browser window width
  htmlToPdfConverter.HtmlViewerWidth = int.Parse(htmlViewerWidthTextBox.Text);

  // Set HTML viewer height in pixels to convert the top part of a HTML page 
  // Leave it not set to convert the entire HTML
  if (htmlViewerHeightTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
      htmlToPdfConverter.HtmlViewerHeight = int.Parse(htmlViewerHeightTextBox.Text);

  // Set PDF page size which can be a predefined size like A4 or a custom size in points 
  // Leave it not set to have a default A4 PDF page
  htmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = SelectedPdfPageSize();

  // Set PDF page orientation to Portrait or Landscape
  // Leave it not set to have a default Portrait orientation for PDF page
  htmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageOrientation = SelectedPdfPageOrientation();

  // Set the maximum time in seconds to wait for HTML page to be loaded 
  // Leave it not set for a default 60 seconds maximum wait time
  htmlToPdfConverter.NavigationTimeout = int.Parse(navigationTimeoutTextBox.Text);

  // Set an adddional delay in seconds to wait for JavaScript or AJAX calls after page load completed
  // Set this property to 0 if you don't need to wait for such asynchcronous operations to finish
  if (conversionDelayTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
      htmlToPdfConverter.ConversionDelay = int.Parse(conversionDelayTextBox.Text);

  // The buffer to receive the generated PDF document
  byte[] outPdfBuffer = null;

  if (convertUrlRadioButton.Checked)
  {
      string url = urlTextBox.Text;

      // Convert the HTML page given by an URL to a PDF document in a memory buffer
      outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrl(url);
  }
  else
  {
      string htmlString = htmlStringTextBox.Text;
      string baseUrl = baseUrlTextBox.Text;

      // Convert a HTML string with a base URL to a PDF document in a memory buffer
      outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(htmlString, baseUrl);
  }

  // Send the PDF as response to browser

  // Set response content type
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

  // Instruct the browser to open the PDF file as an attachment or inline
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0}; filename=Getting_Started.pdf; size={1}",
      openInlineCheckBox.Checked ? "inline" : "attachment", outPdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

  // Write the PDF document buffer to HTTP response
  Response.BinaryWrite(outPdfBuffer);

  // End the HTTP response and stop the current page processing
  Response.End();
}
```

Comment: OK. So can you post reason why your user wants convert HTML to PDF. 
Using evopdf you can create ASHX handler that handler will convert HTML page (or HTML string) to PDF and writes to the response.